# How do I get the average weather for any given zipcode in Perl?

Tags: perl

Is there a Perl module to get the avg. temperature for any given zipcode? For instance, Wikipedia has the Avg. high, avg. low & daily mean temperature [for Los Angeles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Angeles#Climate).

I'd like to do this in Perl somehow but can't find a module to do this (e.g. type in 10001 and get the avg. temp. for New York).

Comment: Whenever you have this sort of question, go to [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org). Spend more than a couple minutes there and you'll find the answer to your problem. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Searching CPAN for "weather"](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=weather&mode=dist) gives you a ton of options including [Google Weather](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Weather-Google), [weather.com](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Weather-Com) and [Weather Underground](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Weather-Underground).

Most of these are just fetching a URL and parsing the resulting XML or JSON.  So if you don't want to use the modules you can do it manually using [LWP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP::Simple) and either [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Simple) or [JSON::Any](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON::Any) to parse the result.

Comment: It is true those modules exist, but the question was for "the average weather" which is based on historical weather. Weather Underground, I think, is the only one of those three with "average" or historical weather, and WU's average is based on airport location -- not ZIP.   Update: Never mind. Sorry. I located the "average" on weather.com and it was better than what I used.

Comment: Oh, I missed the part where they specifically wanted average weather.

Answer (score 1):

`http://www.melissadata.com/lookups/ZipWeather.asp?ZipCode=XXXXX`

For New York: http://www.melissadata.com/lookups/ZipWeather.asp?ZipCode=10001

Then curl and parse the result...